# SQL subquery returns more than 1 row

Tags: sql, subquery

I am using this sql query and it gives me an error " Subquery returns more than 1 row"
what's is the solution for this :

```
  SELECT b.compte_idcompte as idcompte,name,prenom,profilepic,idpost ,description,imagefeeling,textfeeling,urlimages, urlvideos,sharedat as publishedat ,publishedat as sharedat , original_idcompte, original_name,original_prenom , original_photourl, original_desc from (select idpost, post_is_shared.description , post.description as original_desc ,(select idcompte as original_idcompte from compte  where idcompte in (select post.compte_idcompte from post,post_is_shared 
  where post_is_shared.post_idpost = post.idpost
            )) as original_idcompte,(select name as original_name from compte 
  where name in (select compte.name from compte,post,post_is_shared 
  where post_is_shared.post_idpost = post.idpost
   and compte.idcompte = post.compte_idcompte
            )) as original_name, 

 (select prenom as original_prenom from compte where prenom in (select compte.prenom from compte,post,post_is_shared
  where post_is_shared.post_idpost = post.idpost
  and compte.idcompte = post.compte_idcompte))  as original_prenom,
  
        
  (select profilepic as original_photourl from compte 
  where profilepic in (select compte.profilepic from compte,post,post_is_shared
  where post_is_shared.post_idpost = post.idpost
  and compte.idcompte = post.compte_idcompte)) as original_photourl,feeling_idfeeling,post_is_shared.compte_idcompte,sharedat , publishedat,name,prenom,profilepic,imagefeeling,textfeeling
  from post,compte,feeling,post_is_shared 
  where post_is_shared.compte_idcompte='21'
  and post_is_shared.sharedto ='1'
  and compte.idcompte = post_is_shared.compte_idcompte 
  and post.idpost = post_is_shared.post_idpost
  and post.feeling_idfeeling = feeling.idfeeling) as b
  left join (select post_idpost,GROUP_CONCAT(images.url) as urlimages from images 
             group by images.post_idpost) as a 
  on b.idpost = a.post_idpost 
  left join (select post_idpost,GROUP_CONCAT(videos.url) as urlvideos from videos 
             group by videos.post_idpost) as c on b.idpost = c.post_idpost
```

Comment: The solution is not to return more than one value in a subquery, clearly. Take them out one at atime and see which one is causing the issue. You probably missed a join predicate inside it

Comment: original_idcompte
original_name
original_prenom
original_photourl

It looks like on all of the above columns you are trying to return in your subquery are based on a further subquery using an IN statement which would indicate you are trying to return more than one value for that column.

May I also suggest you format code when you post it.  https://poorsql.com/ will do it for you.